# PHP SSH multiple commands

Tags: php, ssh

I am trying to build a ssh script to run multiple commands on a host. My goal is get the output of each command. My target host is a cisco router and for the following script to execute more that one command i need to run it for each command i want to execute which is not a very elegant solution.

```
$cmd = array ('sh run int te 1/1', 'sh run int te 1/2');

for ($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++) {
    $connection = ssh2_connect('10.1.1.1', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd[$i]);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out); }
```

I have created a loop because i was unable to get the output for each command in the same stream. Since i guess that the php is terminating the ssh connections at the end of each stream.

What i would like to achieve is to execute several commands and get the output in the same stream (if posible).

I am editing the post to answer the sugestions made by @Melvin Koopmans and @LSerni.

if i change the code as sugested (this was someting i also tried before) the second command returns an error. here is the cli output:
the script changed:

```
$cmds = array ('sh run int te 1/1', 'sh run int te 1/2');

$connection = ssh2_connect('10.1.1.1', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');

foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec( $connection, $cmd );
    stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO );
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);}
```

the output from cli

```
interface TenGigabitEthernet1/1
description trunk
switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,2,3,4,5,6,10
switchport mode trunk
auto qos trust
storm-control broadcast include multicast
storm-control broadcast level 1.00
spanning-tree guard loop
service-policy input AutoQos-4.0-Input-Policy
service-policy output AutoQos-4.0-Output-Policy
ip dhcp snooping trust
end

PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Unable to request a channel from remote host       in C:\Users\SMS\Downloads\php_scripts\ssh.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  stream_set_blocking() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\SMS\Downloads\php_scripts\ssh.php on line 14
PHP Warning:  ssh2_fetch_stream() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\Users\SMS\Downloads\php_scripts\ssh.php on line 15
PHP Warning:  stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\Users\SMS\Downloads\php_scripts\ssh.php on line 16
```

I am only getting the output from the first command "sh run int te 1/1".

Comment: Could you not implode the array with "&&" so that it does all commands one after another automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You are repeating the connection stage. Try this instead:

```
$cmds = array ('sh run int te 1/1', 'sh run int te 1/2');

$connection = ssh2_connect('10.1.1.1', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'user', 'pass');

foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $cmd);
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
    echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);
}
```

I tested now on a Ubuntu machine (14.04-LTS), and it works:

```
I say 'who', answer was: lserni   :0           Jan 21 11:25 (console)
I say 'date', answer was: Thu Feb 16 09:55:52 CET 2017
```

<sup><sup>...well, apart from the fact that I forgot an open console login on that machine :-(</sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend initiating a new connection on every single loop, instead set the connection first then loop over an array of commands and push the output to an array. Like so:

```
$cmds = [ 'ls', 'ps ux' ];

$connection = ssh2_connect( '127.0.0.1', 22 );
ssh2_auth_password( $connection, 'username', 'password' );

$output = [];

foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
    $stream = ssh2_exec( $connection, $cmd );
    stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
    $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO );
    $output[] = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
}
```

This will push all of the output to the array `$output`.

Now you can loop over $output, or you can choose to give output the key of yoru command so you can access it:

```
$output[$cmd] = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
```

And then, for example, call: `$output['ls']`