# PHP/SSH: Multiple command in the same session (do confirmation)

Tags: php, session, ssh, confirmation

I've a problem with PHP and the SSH-Extension/Net-SSH-Libary. I use it for sending commands to a NetApp-Filer. So I want to create/delete Volumes on the filer. Creation for Volumes is no problem.

But when I want to delete them, the filer ask's for an confirmation ("Are you sure you want to delete.. y/n") and I can't give the NetApp this information. For every exec-Command ist starts a new session.

Is it possible to run more commands in the same session or give them a confirmation of some commands?

My Code (only Volume delete):

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
            $ssh = new Net_SSH2('172.22.31.53');
            if (!$ssh->login('admin', '12Test')) {
                exit('Login Failed');
            }

            echo $ssh->exec("vol unmount $row->name");
            sleep(1);
            echo $ssh->exec("vol offline $row->name");
            sleep(1);
            echo $ssh->exec("vol delete $vol_name \n y");
            $loesch = mysqli_query($db, "DELETE FROM volumes WHERE id = '$id'");
            header('Location: splash.html');

?>
```

Thank's in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I see a few possible solutions:

1. use **`\n`** :

   ```
   $ssh->exec("cd mydir\n./script");
   ```

   Or create a script with your commands, for example `script.sh` and save it in UNIX format:

   ```
   cd mydir
   ./script
   ```

   Then **exec** the script:

   ```
   $script = file_get_contents("script.sh");
   $ssh->exec($script);
   ```
2. Use either a `;` or a `&&` to separate the commands.

   ```
   ssh2_exec($connection, 'command1 ; command2');   //run both uncondtionally)
   ssh2_exec($connection, 'command1 && command2');  //run command2 only if command1 succeeds
   ```
3. Use [stream_set_blocking()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.stream-set-blocking.php) like this:

   ```
   $cmds = [ 'ls', 'ps ux' ];
   $connection = ssh2_connect( '127.0.0.1', 22 );
   ssh2_auth_password( $connection, 'username', 'password' );
   $output = [];
   foreach ($cmds as $cmd) {
       $stream = ssh2_exec( $connection, $cmd );
       stream_set_blocking( $stream, true );
       $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO );
       $output[] = stream_get_contents($stream_out);
   }
   ```

   You will find all the output in the array `$output`.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268771/php-ssh-multiple-commands)

Comment: I do not think you have tested your answer.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski why the downvote? This has been tested. Kindly check the reference too.

Comment: I did not like the answer in the way it formerly was posted. Now it's better, so I retracted my downvote.